# android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" - without any EditText causes strange behavior like a D-pad

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I had an activity that opens already with the keyboard opened because I use the attribute android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" at AndroidManifest.
But in this activity I don't have any Edit Text (only one button) and I need to read each character typed (once per time) by user.
So I had overridden the dispatchKeyEvent to read each character.

The problem is that since the keyboard is being showed and there is no one Edit Text, when click in any character Android OS kind selects the button (or any other view) on screen. This selection is kind I was using a D-pad.
And if the back button is pressed it will "select" any other view from back activity.

I think that since there is no Edit Text to works with keyboard the activity does not know how to handle the characters typed.

I had attached at Tiny server a simple project with two activities that can be used as sample to reproduce the issue: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=70317553185010262971

Also had attached a screenshot at TinyPic:

- http://tinypic.com/r/2uhmwdy/8

Below also are all my codes:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testbug"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testbug.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.testbug.TestActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java (1º activity)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnStart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**TestActivity.java (2º activity)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

TextView tvType;
Button testButton;
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_count);

    tvType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_type);
    testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    count++;
    if(count==6){
        hideKeyboard();
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

private void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
}
```

**Layouts:**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_count.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TestButton"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:text="Press any key 3 times to Hide keyboard\n Then Press Back button. The same behavior of selection of button will happens on back activity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

dispatchKeyEvent only works for physical buttons-  think Blackberry.  You have a lot of work ahead of you.

First off, in android the keyboard is owned by a view, NOT by the app.  SO some view will get the keyboard events.  This view must return a non-NULL value in onCreateInputConnection(), with an object that will be called when data comes from the keyboard.

Secondly, you will not always get individual key events.  Most Android keyboards work word at a time.  This is particularly true for autocorrect features and Swyping.  You'll need to consider this in your design.

Thirdly, you need to implement all of the features expected by the keyboards from an edit text.  This means correctly supporting composing text, cursor movement notifications, etc.  If you react differently than expected, you may screw up autocomplete and swype functionalities and start getting really weird (and wrong) results from the keyboard.

Really, I highly recommend against doing this if you're actually going to do any type of word input.  If you're just using characters as NOT words, you should tell it your view is NO_SUGGESTIONS and input type NULL so keyboards *should* go into dummy mode-  although no promises.

Comment: thanks a lot for explanation.
So I cant have the keyboard without a view?
I really need to read only a character and NOT any word. In my application I read only the first letter (typed by user) of a word and my app auto completes the word. But there is no Edit Text on activity. :(
You had also sad that dispatchKeyEvent is for physical, do you know what should I use in my app that would be more correct?

Thanks a lot for your help, I have been working on this long time ago and no one had gave me so close answer to solve this.

Comment: You can get one to appear without a view, but without a view it won't be linked to anything-  the data will just disappear (and the keyboard itself will get a lot of errors that it hopefully will not crash on).  It doesn't have to be an edit text view though-  anything can work if it has a non-null return from getInputConnection and you pass it that view when you cause the keyboard to show.

Comment: You can get what you want to work, its just not low effort.  I'd go with making some view in your layout the view that ties to the keyboard.  Focus it like you would an edit text to make the keyboard show.  Make sure to use TYPE_NULL and NO_SUGGESTIONS to put the keyboard into dumb mode.  Then the InputConnection object you return from the onCreateInputConnection will get the keyboard events, not dispatchKeyEvent.

Comment: Ok Thank you.
I'm using the keyboard without a view so it is not linked to anything but I'm using the dispatchKeyEvent, so it gets the character type on keyboard, but happens the D-pad behavior mentioned as issue...

Comment: Sorry Gabe, but I have been trying lots of codes with your suggestions and no one worked for me. Maybe I had tried it wrong.
I'm not finding a way to do that.